# Which phone color to cater to?

Tags: color, iphone, instagram, samsung

As many of you know the color on most Samsung phones are pretty saturated, and the colors on iPhones are pretty flat.

As I own a Samsung S7 I've been catering to that for Instagram photos but after looking at my brothers iphone they seem more realistic and less saturated than desired.

What is most common for photographers to cater to regarding color on phones?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Are you asking what degree of color saturation is most popular on Instagram?

Comment: @MikeW I think OP wants to know for which phone he/she should optimise the colours for. Can't really be answered as there are a ton of displays on the market and all look different.

Comment: @jannik Pitt that is correct. While it may be sort of an invalid question, there must be a phone most people would go with.

Comment: Why don't you get a calibrated display and cater for the artistic style you think's better...

Comment: @JannikPitt Oh right, gotcha.  So I updload photos and they look good on my Samsung, but on my brother's iPhone they look dull. Not sure why I didn't get that on the first reading.

Comment: @crazy dino I am currently calibrated, results really look like neither.

Comment: @Flo your missing my point... Why are you catering for a device. Cater for the style YOU prefer it's your 'art'. On your calibrated screen if you prefer images with higher saturation edit all your images like that, if you prefer the flatter images, edit like that.

Comment: What color profile are you using for your exports?

Comment: @Dino I do use a color calibrated screen however 95% of the time the photo it's seen is by phone so it makes sense to make my vision look like what I want on a sertain platform.

Comment: @scottbb standard sRGB

Comment: @Flo you don't happen to be a developer by any chance? It appears youre looking into it with a more technical mindset over subjective... Are you talking about the way the camera captures the image, (the image taken on device x is more saturated than y), the way the image is displayed on the display (the same image looks more saturated on device x over y) or how you want to edit your images (device x produces more saturated images. More people use x. I must make my images look like that). Or most people use device x. I must profile my images to appear best on it. Currently it's not clear.

Comment: @crazy dino I'm not a photo developer if that's what you're asking, I am however a web developer. So you are more right with the device X displays images more saturated than Y however more people use device Y so you would cater to that device during the editing process in regards to color selection and saturation. My original question is asking, is there a phone display which most photographers cater to for Instagram or do they just use their calibrated settings and it just turns out how it turns out?

Comment: @Flo I meant software/web developer etc as it involves the getting things right for various devices ;) (oh IE6 how I don't miss you). This is why editing to a correctly calibrated screen rather than devices IS important as what you see IS the correct article. It also allows a degree of future proofing as when the next iteration of device comes around who's to say the colour profiling will remaing the same. At the end of the day for a generic instagram end user will it make much difference though?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Developing for non calibrated devices?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/76486/developing-for-non-calibrated-devices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general answer is "neither", but it depends entirely on what your target audience is.  If you know that your target audience will be using a particular device, it is fine to mix for that device specifically, but for general release, this is why color spaces and standards exist.

If you adjust your color on a well calibrated display in a standard color space, then it will look consistent relative to what a user is used to seeing on their device.  It won't be perfect on any device that doesn't accurately reproduce the color space, but ideally each device will be at least somewhat close, even if it varies in one direction or another.

Designing for this conceptual "center point" keeps it looking ok on any consumer device and consistent with other things using the same standard color space.  It also means that whenever someone views it on something that accurately implements the color space, they'll see exactly what you were going for.

Comment: Perfect, thank you this is what I was looking for.